# Python Tkinter Toplevel runs without calling

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.6

Hello I have some very simple python code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

def createnewguiprojectgui():
    asktk = Toplevel()
    asktk.title("Create new gui source")
    Label(asktk, text="Gui options").pack(side=TOP)
    askfilename = Entry(asktk)
    askfilename.insert(0, "Source name")
    askfilename.pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)
    yesfornew = Button(asktk, text="cancel", command=createnewguiproject())
    nofornew = Button(asktk, text="cancel",command=) #a command
def createnewguiproject():
    pass


def main():


    mainparent = Tk()
    w, h = mainparent.winfo_screenwidth(), mainparent.winfo_screenheight()
    mainparent.title("GUI CREATOR")
    mainmenu = Menu(mainparent)
    filemenu = Menu(mainmenu,tearoff = 0)
    filemenu.add_command(label="New project", command = createnewguiprojectgui())
    mainmenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
    separator = Frame(height=2, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN)
    separator.pack(fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
    mainparent.config(menu=mainmenu)
    mainmenu.focus_set()
    mainparent.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, every time I run ths script, the asktk toplevel pops up with the mainparent Tk, even if I don't press the menu bar, and the focus is set to asktk. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command here is calling the function that creates a new window object onload rather than when New Project is selected.

```
filemenu.add_command(label="New project", command = createnewguiprojectgui())
```

You need to change it to:

```
filemenu.add_command(label="New project", command = createnewguiprojectgui)
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I understood why it's running by itself. Thank you, and the rest of the answers, too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: in the line that has ...

```
filemenu.add_command(label="New project", command = createnewguiprojectgui())
```

take the () off the end of createnewguiprojectgui.  In other words, pass the function, don't call it.

The same should be true for the following line ...

```
yesfornew = Button(asktk, text="cancel", command=createnewguiproject())
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't call the function `command=createnewguiproject()`. Remove the (). Your `createnewguiproject()` method gets called as soon as the main loop starts.

Do this:

```
yesfornew = Button(asktk, text="cancel", command=createnewguiproject)
```

Or if you want to send some argument then:

```
yesfornew = Button(asktk, text="cancel", command=lambda:createnewguiproject(args))
```